# How to rearrange data?

Tags: r

I have a sample data below.

```
classobj    var1    var2    var3    var4
       1       2       0      10       4
       2       1       1      64       2
       2       3       1      15       2
       2       1       2      46       1
       2       3       1      13       1
       1       2       0      10       4
       2       1       1      45       2
       2       2       2      45       2
       2       3       1      11       1
       2       3       2       9       1
```

`classobj=1` is the household and `classobj==2` are the members of the household. So this portion of the data belongs to 1 household.

```
 classobj   var1    var2    var3    var4
        1      2       0      10       4
        2      1       1      64       2
        2      3       1      15       2
        2      1       2      46       1
        2      3       1      13       1
```

What I would like to do is remove all values in a row of `classobj==1`. Then look for `var1==1` (head of the family) from `classobj==2`. Copy all row values for `var1==1` and add it as a value for ``classobj==1. If there are more than 1 `var==1`, then look for var3. Copy the values for the var3 with the highest value.

Edited: the output should be this

```
classobj    var1    var2    var3    var4
       1       1       1      64       2
       2       1       1      64       2
       2       3       1      15       2
       2       1       2      46       1
       2       3       1      13       1
       1       1       1      45       2
       2       1       1      45       2
       2       2       2      45       2
       2       3       1      11       1
       2       3       2       9       1
```

im planning to use this code to remove all the values if `classobj==1`

```
DF[DF$Classobj == 1, 2:4] <- NA
```

the remaining prob would be how can I look for `var1==1` and copy its values.

PS.

Sorry. It should not be var2 but var3. I edited the post.

Comment: Is your data ordered? i.e. `classobj = 1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2...`

Comment: In your example, shouldn't the row with `var2 == 2` get copied?

Comment: @Codoremifa: only the values from var1 to var4 should be copied. all values for classobj should be retained.

Comment: @NathanG: yes, the data is structured in that way, 1,2,2,2,2 belongs to one family. the next rows with 1,2,2,2,2 is another family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling I'm missing something in the question, or misreading it, but I'm thinking along these lines -

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)

# columns for which value is to be copied
valuecolumns = setdiff(colnames(dt),'classobj')

# marking each family with a unique flag
dt[,flag := 0]
dt[classobj == 1,flag := 1]
dt[,flag := cumsum(flag)]

# temporarily removing the classobj == 1 rows
dt <- dt[classobj != 1]

# marking cases where unique var1 = 1 is there
dt[,var1eq1 := .SD[var1 == 1, .N], by = 'flag']

# re-addingclassobj == 1 rows where multiple var1 == 1 exist
dt <- rbind(dt,dt[var1eq1 > 1 & classobj != 1, .SD[which.max(var2)], by = 'flag'][,classobj := as.integer(1)])
# re-addingclassobj == 1 rows with max var2 values
dt <- rbind(dt,dt[var1eq1 == 1 & classobj != 1, .SD[var1 == 1], by = 'flag'][,classobj := as.integer(1)])
```

Output -

```
> dt
    classobj var1 var2 var3 var4 flag var1eq1
 1:        2    1    1   64    2    1       2
 2:        2    3    1   15    2    1       2
 3:        2    1    2   46    1    1       2
 4:        2    3    1   13    1    1       2
 5:        2    1    1   45    2    2       1
 6:        2    2    2   45    2    2       1
 7:        2    3    1   11    1    2       1
 8:        2    3    2    9    1    2       1
 9:        1    1    2   46    1    1       2
10:        1    1    1   45    2    2       1
```

Comment: Thanks for this! however Im getting error when i run the last two codes about rbind ...Warning message:
In data.table::.rbind.data.table(...) :
  Argument 2 has names in a different order. Columns will be bound by name for consistency with base. You can drop names (by using an unnamed list) and the columns will then be joined by position, or set use.names=FALSE. Alternatively, explicitly setting use.names to TRUE will remove this warning.

Comment: this code here # temporarily removing the classobj == 1 rows
dt <- dt[classobj != 1] remove the rows with classobj == 1.
thus this code here creates a new variable var1eq1 with values all 1.
# marking cases where unique var1 = 1 is there
dt[,var1eq1 := .SD[var1 == 1, .N], by = 'flag']

Comment: That warning, like it says, is about the columns not being in the same order and r binding the columns by name. Nothing to worry about. I do not understand your second comment.

Comment: I see thanks!... sorry.. ok i see the output of the codes as I run it. however, rows for classobj==1 are totally removed. whats the code so that the classobj==1 are still retained but its values are replace by the values of var1==1? The output is the same as i stated above.

Comment: `classobj == 1` rows are removed and appended in the rbind. The order of rows has changed though. You should be able to fix that using the `flag` column though. I've added the output to my answer in case there's some discrepancy.

Comment: Thanks for this,but is there a way that the postion of classobj are retained? the classobj==1 is the household data and classobj==2 are members of that household preceeding them. since the rows are rearrange, members of the households might be wrongly added to a different household. Also, from your output, ill take those with flag =  that is, Household 1.  Case 9 seems to have the classobj==1.. Its representing Household 1. This should not be, Case 1 should be representing Household 1.

Comment: Im not sure how to do this. But i think the code should work as: First, Erase all values in classobj==1. Probably we can use this code. dt[dt$classobj == 1, 2:5] <- NA. Then create your variable var1eq1 that would be set to 1 if var1==1 (or var1==1 & var2==max number, in case of multiple var1==1), rest is 0. Thats per flag value. Lastly, copy the values from [var1eq1==1, 2:5, by=flag] and paste that to [classobj==1, 2:5, by=flag].

Comment: The `flag` column uniquely identifies households. Even though row number 9 is `classobj == 1`, the flag identifies it as belonging to family 1. Similarly, flag identifes row 10 as belonging to family 2. You can `setkeyv(dt,c('flag','classob'))` if the order really bothers you but IMO, `flag` and `classobj` together should negate the need for the order. If it is still not clear, please post the exact output you expect for the ten rows you've posted.

Comment: I made a mistake. its should be var3 not var2. the values are correct but if we can retain the order, it would be best. :-D

Comment: i rearranged using the setkeyv. I think this is what I want. Thanks so much for your help codomerifa!!!!! I appreaciate it a lot. :-D :-D